# How to prevent dynamically added parent class from adding to its child elements in Angular Material,mat-selection-list?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular6

I have created a dialog with a list of options(users) which can be selected, using `mat-selection-list`. I have a use case where I should disable the list of already selected users from getting selected/clicked again.

So, I get the selected users from the event, add a flag to know if the user has already been selected or not, and disable the `mat-list-option` based on the returned boolean value from the flag which I have. Here is the code for that.

```
<mat-selection-list 
  #listItem 
  (selectionChange)="handleSelection($event, listItem.selectedOptions)">
  <mat-list-option 
    *ngFor="let item of filteredArray" 
    [value]="item" 
    [disabled]="item.isSelected">
    {{getDisplayValue(item)}}
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Now, the problem is, I want to show a tick mark for the already selected users as well since `mat-list-option` has a `mat-checkbox` child element.

So when i disable the `mat-list-option`(parent) , it also adds class `mat-psuedo-checkbox-disabled` to the checkbox(child) as well. I want to prevent this from happening.

Or suggest me an efficient way to override the `mat-checkbox` class and add `checked` class to it, even if the `mat-list-option` has disabled class added to it.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

UPDATE: 
Solved it by adding mat-list-option selected property to that. How stupid was i to miss that.Lol.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue?

Comment: Sure,as of now I am not in a place to do so. I might able to do that by tomorrow morning. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of filteredArray" [value]="item" [disabled]="item.isSelected" [selected]="item.isSelected">
```

Able to solve this with a help of my colleague.

i wasn't looking at the right place.